# pointer motion. why are numbers so high? why does it print info in blocks not a constant stream?

Tags: c, mouseevent, mousemove, xlib

Hi! I am trying to write a program where I need to report the position of every mouse motion. I have called the `XSelectInput()` function with a `PointerMotionMask` mask. Everything seems to work alright but the numbers after printing don't appear after every movement, they appear in blocks and also the numbers in `event.xmotion.x` and `event.xmotion.y` are very high, in the hundred thousands.
What is causing these large numbers?
Also is my program getting every number and reporting it immediately or is it being stored in a queue and sent in blocks to the terminal?
Thanks

Here's my event loop:

```
while(1)
    {
        XNextEvent(display, &event);
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case Expose: 
                glClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
                    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
                    glFlush();
                    glXSwapBuffers( display, glxwin );              
                break;
            case MotionNotify:
                printf("%d, %d", event.xmotion.x, event.xmotion.y);
                break;
            case ButtonPress: exit(1);
            default: break;     
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Try adding `\n` in your printf for the buffering. (No idea about the coordinate system though.)

Comment: don't duplicate questions (you could just edit the previous one)

Answer (score 0):

Besides printing a newline at the end, you could also do a `'\r'` at the end it it will move the cursor to the beginning of the existing line, so it will just print over itself each time.  To make this work better, change the digit formatting to be a fixed size, like:

```
printf("%4d, %4d  \r", event.xmotion.x, event.xmotion.y);
fflush(stdout) ;
```